# Need an regexp pattern to get a teft between brackets

Tags: php, regex, brackets

I have a text string like:

```
background:url(//img.website.com/asd/asd/i3/1746380416/TB2KDVEXfSM.eBjSZFNXXbgYpXa_!!1746380416.jpg_40x40q90.jpg) center no-repeat;
background:url(//img.website.com/asd/asd/i3/1746380416/TB2RR8FXmiK.eBjSZFDXXbxZVXa_!!1746380416.jpg_40x40q90.jpg) center no-repeat;
background:url(//img.website.com/asd/asd/i1/1746380416/TB2lHCuaOKO.eBjSZPhXXXqcpXa_!!1746380416.jpg_40x40q90.jpg) center no-repeat;
```

How can I get only the following text?

```
//img.website.com/asd/asd/i3/1746380416/TB2KDVEXfSM.eBjSZFNXXbgYpXa_!!1746380416.jpg_40x40q90.jpg
```

Comment: Repeatedly match `background:url\((.*)\)` and then use capture group one to get the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match that exact text (as you state), you don't need regex:

```
$match = strpos('//img.website.com/asd/asd/i3/1746380416/TB2KDVEXfSM.eBjSZFNXXbgYpXa_!!1746380416.jpg_40x40q90.jpg', $your_test);
if($match !== false)
    echo('The string was found');
```

If you want to match any URL:

```
preg_match("/(background:url\()(.*?)(\))/", $your_text, $matches);
var_dump($matches[2]);
```

If you want to match all URLs:

```
preg_match_all("/(background:url\()(.*?)(\))/", $your_text, $matches);
foreach($matches[2] as $match)
    var_dump($match[2]);
```